# null pointer at the spinner

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I have got problem with programing fragment. I found null exception  at the spinner . i dont know why the spinner is null :( I try evrything i use view, getActivity() but allweys is null . I need suggestions..help me :)

```
    /*

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.calculator.mycalculator.R;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment implements
        OnItemSelectedListener, TextWatcher, OnClickListener {
    final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    int mCurrentPosition = -1;

    // notri so zapisane vse enote
    private ArrayList<Enota> enote;
    private ArrayList<String> e;
    private ArrayAdapter enoteAdapter;

    // Spiner za vhodne podatke
    private Spinner inputSpinner;

    // Spinner za izhodne podatke
    private Spinner outputSpinner;

    private double inputAmount;
    private boolean inputValid;

    // indeksa ki povesta katera je trenutna stvar izbrana
    private int unitInputIndex1;
    private int unitInputIndex2;

    // normalizirana mera ki je trenutno prikazana
    private double inputRate1;
    private double inputRate2;

    // rabimo tudi ime kot so moÄŤ, kot itd..
    String category;

    View v;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        }
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
        e = new ArrayList<String>();

        category = "kot";
        this.enote = EnoteUpravljalec
                .getUnits(this.category, v.getContext(), 1);
        String[] unitNames = new String[this.enote.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.enote.size(); i++)
            unitNames[i] = enote.get(i).getLocalizedName();
        enoteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(v.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, unitNames);
        enoteAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        inputSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.unitInput1);
        outputSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.unitInput2);
        try {
            inputSpinner.setAdapter(enoteAdapter);
            outputSpinner.setAdapter(enoteAdapter);
            inputSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            outputSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            EditText edit_text = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.enotaVrednost);
            edit_text.addTextChangedListener(this);
            this.inputValid = false;

            setConversionOutput("");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        this.unitInputIndex1 = -1;
        this.unitInputIndex2 = -1;
        this.inputRate1 = -1.0;
        this.inputRate2 = -1.0;
        // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
        // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
        // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // During startup, check if there are arguments passed to the fragment.
        // onStart is a good place to do this because the layout has already
        // been
        // applied to the fragment at this point so we can safely call the
        // method
        // below that sets the article text.
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            // Set article based on argument passed in
            updateArticleView(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
        } else if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
            // Set article based on saved instance state defined during
            // onCreateView
            updateArticleView(mCurrentPosition);
        }
    }

    public void updateArticleView(int position) {

        mCurrentPosition = position;

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            category = "kot";
            break;
        case 1:
            category = "povrsina";
            break;
        case 2:
            category = "energija";
            break;
        case 3:
            category = "moc";
            break;
        case 4:
            category = "dolzina";
            break;
        case 5:
            category = "masa";
            break;
        case 6:
            category = "tlak";
            break;
        case 7:
            category = "hitrost";
            break;
        case 8:
            category = "temperatura";
            break;
        case 9:
            category = "cas";
            break;
        case 10:
            category = "volumen";
            break;

        }

        e = new ArrayList<String>();
        // dobime ime kategorije
        // this.category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");
        // dobimo enoto

        this.enote = EnoteUpravljalec.getUnits(this.category, getActivity(), 1);
        String[] unitNames = new String[this.enote.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.enote.size(); i++)
            unitNames[i] = enote.get(i).getLocalizedName();
        enoteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, unitNames);
        enoteAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        inputSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.unitInput1);
        outputSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.unitInput2);

        try {
            inputSpinner.setAdapter(enoteAdapter);
            outputSpinner.setAdapter(enoteAdapter);
            inputSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            outputSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            setConversionOutput("");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        // TextView article = (TextView)
        // getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);
        // article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // Save the current article selection in case we need to recreate the
        // fragment
        outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
    }

    private void setConversionOutput(String s) {
        TextView v = (TextView) getView().findViewById(
                R.id.unit_conversion_output);
        v.setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable amount) {
        if (amount.length() == 0) {
            // If no text is entered, the input is invalid.
            this.inputValid = false;
        } else {

            String text = amount.toString();
            try {
                this.inputAmount = Double.parseDouble(text);
                this.inputValid = true;

                NarediPretvorbo();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                this.inputValid = false;

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    private Enota getUnit(int index) {

        return enote.get(index);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.unitInput1:
            // The "from" unit has been changed.
            unitInputIndex1 = position;
            inputRate1 = getUnit(position).getNormalizedValue();
            break;
        case R.id.unitInput2:
            // The "to" unit has been changed.
            unitInputIndex2 = position;
            inputRate2 = getUnit(unitInputIndex2).getNormalizedValue();
            break;
        }

        // If something is selected in both spinners, make a unit conversion.
        NarediPretvorbo();
    }

    public void NarediPretvorbo() {

        if (this.unitInputIndex1 == -1 || this.unitInputIndex2 == -1)
            return;

        double vred;
        if (this.inputValid)
            vred = this.inputAmount;
        else
            vred = 1.0;

        String LokalnaEnota1 = getUnit(unitInputIndex1).getLocalizedName();
        String LokalnaEnota2 = getUnit(unitInputIndex2).getLocalizedName();

        double resultAmount = 0.0;

        if (this.category.equalsIgnoreCase("temperatura")) {

            if (LokalnaEnota1.equalsIgnoreCase(LokalnaEnota2)) {
                resultAmount = vred;
            } else if (LokalnaEnota1.equalsIgnoreCase("fahrenheit")) {
                if (LokalnaEnota2.equalsIgnoreCase("celsius")) {
                    resultAmount = (vred - 32) * (5 / 9.0);
                } else if (LokalnaEnota2.equalsIgnoreCase("kelvin")) {
                    resultAmount = (vred - 32) * (5 / 9.0) + 273.15;
                }
            } else if (LokalnaEnota1.equalsIgnoreCase("celsius")) {
                if (LokalnaEnota2.equalsIgnoreCase("fahrenheit")) {
                    resultAmount = (vred * (9 / 5.0)) + 32;
                } else if (LokalnaEnota2.equalsIgnoreCase("kelvin")) {
                    resultAmount = vred + 273.15;
                }
            } else if (LokalnaEnota1.equalsIgnoreCase("kelvin")) {
                if (LokalnaEnota2.equalsIgnoreCase("fahrenheit")) {
                    resultAmount = ((vred - 273.15) * 1.8) + 32;
                } else if (LokalnaEnota2.equalsIgnoreCase("celsius")) {
                    resultAmount = vred - 273.15;
                }

                e.add(category
                        + " "
                        + vred
                        + " "
                        + getUnit(unitInputIndex1).getLocalizedName()
                                .toLowerCase()
                        + " "
                        + resultAmount
                        + " "
                        + getUnit(unitInputIndex2).getLocalizedName()
                                .toLowerCase());
            }
        } else {
            // Actually make a conversion!
            resultAmount = vred * (this.inputRate1 / this.inputRate2);
            if (vred > 1.0 && !this.category.equalsIgnoreCase("temperature"))
                e.add(category
                        + " iz "
                        + vred
                        + " "
                        + getUnit(unitInputIndex1).getLocalizedName()
                                .toLowerCase()
                        + " v "
                        + resultAmount
                        + " "
                        + getUnit(unitInputIndex2).getLocalizedName()
                                .toLowerCase());
        }

        // Set the result of the conversion.
        String result = Double.toString(resultAmount);
        setConversionOutput(result);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.unitInput1:
            this.unitInputIndex1 = -1;
            this.inputRate1 = -1.0;
            break;
        case R.id.unitInput2:
            this.unitInputIndex2 = -1;
            this.inputRate2 = -1.0;
            break;
        }
    }


}
```

Article view:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@+string/from_currency_amount_label"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/currency_converter_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@+string/from_currency_label"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/from_currency_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@+string/to_currency_label"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/to_currency_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currency_conversion_output"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/last_updated"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

There is exception:

```
    08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.calculator.mycalculator/com.Converter.myConverter.Unit.EnotaMainHendler}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.Converter.myConverter.Unit.EnotaMainHendler.onCreate(EnotaMainHendler.java:21)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    ... 11 more
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.Converter.myConverter.Unit.ArticleFragment.onCreateView(ArticleFragment.java:95)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1099)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1201)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:292)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
08-24 17:04:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spinner with id `unitInput1` does not exist in your provided xml. Replace your these lines-

```
    inputSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.unitInput1);
    outputSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.unitInput2);
```

with these lines-

```
    inputSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.from_currency_spinner);
    outputSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.to_currency_spinner);
```